# Schengen short term visa document requirements and chances

Tags: indian-citizens, schengen-visas, austria

I recently applied for Schengen short term visa for touring Austria and Italy. This is my first time travelling to a Schengen country while my wife has visited the area 3 times.

I have the following documents furnished:

1. Valid passport not expiring in next 5 years
2. Travel insurance coverage for £30000
3. Confirmed flight tickets (To and fro)
4. Confirmed hotel bookings, majority of them (12 days out of 16 days stay) paid upfront.
5. Income tax returns for last 3 years
6. Payslips for last 3 months (INR 1372000 which roughly translates to EUR 14500 per annum)
7. Bank balance of (INR 400000 or EUR 5000) in two accounts.
8. Cover letter explaining purpose as well as complete itinerary.
9. NOC from my employer about the exact number of days of leave and tentative return date.

We will be staying in Austria for 8 days, traveling from Austria to Italy on 9th day and stay at Italy for 8 days (including the travel day)

I applied for Austria as it is my first destination even if the stay is considered as same in both the countries.

Most often the rejection reason is that the proofs submitted are not enough to cover the entire stay in Schengen area. Given that, the account balance and salary slips provided (mentioned above) are sufficient to get a short term visa? What is the minimum expected bank balance or assets to get the short term tourist visa?

On another note, I have applied for multiple entry since the vfs global employee told me to enter multiple entry. Will it be a problem?

(Edit the last part out if the question is not relevant)

Comment: Do not ask for "minimum expected bank balance" because this can induce you to park money. The minimum depends on circumstances. A single student which go just 4 days (from nearby country) has different expectation that a person who travel for business (having cost already paid reduce also the amount). In any case: do no look only finance. Document also the reason you will not remain in Europe (good work in India, family relations, etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Asking* for multiple entry should not be grounds for rejection. It may or may not be granted.

And I would say that most rejections we're seeing here are because the applicant don't understand that they need to show *stable and documented* income in excess of their *reasonable* living expenses. The *pattern* is more important than the final balance. [This question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab) is for the UK, but the principle is the same.

Comment: Thanks for the info @o.m. I have expenses in January this year for my marriage. But apart from that, it follows a steady cycle. My cover letter also indicates that the travel is for honeymoon.

Comment: @nightgaunt According to https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/sites/homeaffairs/files/e-library/documents/policies/borders-and-visas/schengen/docs/handbook-annex_25.pdf the minimum fixed daily subsistence amount is €26.33 per person for Italy. There are no reference amounts for Austria.